# "duplicate" rows - how to select distinct

Tags: sql, duplicates, rows

I have a table with this structure

```
id1     id2
--------------
10     2
2     10
12    15
```

I need to select "distinct" using SQL in the sense that rows 1 and 2 are considered the same

So I need a query that results in

```
10    2
12   15
```

or

```
2    10
12   15
```

Both are fine.

Any good ideas. This problem is driving me crazy :-)

Answer (score 2):

One simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where a < b or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.b = t.a and t2.a = t.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a DBMS that supports `LEAST` and `GREATEST` you can use these to get ordered pairs:

```
select distinct
  least(id1, id2) as lesser_id,
  greatest(id1, id2) as greater_id
from mytable;
```

In a DBMS that doesn't support these functions , you can use `CASE` expressions to achieve the same:

```
select distinct
  case when id1 <= id2 then id1 else id2 as lesser_id,
  case when id1 >= id2 then id1 else id2 as greater_id
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2 
FROM (
    SELECT id1, id2 FROM mytable
    UNION
    SELECT id2, id1 FROM mytable
) AS combinations
```

Comment: No. This would get every pair twice (i.e. both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`), which is exactly what the OP doesn't want. `DISTINCT` is superfluous by the way, as `UNION` already removes all duplicates.

Comment: Ok, you're right. This answer is wrong. I should have tested it before. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm posting another working alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using relations instead of a DISTINCT clause:

```
SELECT A.id1, A.id2
FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN mytable B ON A.id1 > B.id1 AND A.id1 = B.id2 AND A.id2 = B.id1
WHERE B.id1 IS NULL
```